Why should I not use Id as a field in feature engineering for ML
While feature engineering and deriving features why should I not use I’d as a field for tasks like regressions

ID can certaintly be used as a "feature" in some contexts. Consider a user ID where you have multiple rows of the same user id over multiple different sessions. You would expect metrics from these sessions to be correlated because they originate from the same user!

An Id, like a person’s name, is typically a unique identifier with no meaningful relationship to the target variable. Since it doesn’t carry any inherent pattern or information relevant to the outcome, it usually lacks statistical significance and can introduce noise into the model
